# How can I extract the angle from a function that determines if a circle is colliding with a line?

Tags: math, geometry, game-physics, trigonometry, physics

So I have the following code that works fine

I've taken it from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192477/circle-line-segment-collision

I am now trying to figure out where along this function I can determine the angle in which the circle is hitting the line. Instead of returning true I'd like it to return the angle, since I didn't write the function myself going through it to try and figure this out myself has been a bit of a struggle. Wondering if someone excellent at math can help me figure this out at first glance. Thank you!

```
  // Function to check intercept of line seg and circle
    // A,B end points of line segment
    // C center of circle
    // radius of circle
    // returns true if touching or crossing else false   
    function doesLineInterceptCircle(A, B, C, radius) {
        var dist;
        const v1x = B.x - A.x;
        const v1y = B.y - A.y;
        const v2x = C.x - A.x;
        const v2y = C.y - A.y;
        // get the unit distance along the line of the closest point to
        // circle center
        const u = (v2x * v1x + v2y * v1y) / (v1y * v1y + v1x * v1x);

        // if the point is on the line segment get the distance squared
        // from that point to the circle center
        if(u >= 0 && u <= 1){
            dist  = (A.x + v1x * u - C.x) ** 2 + (A.y + v1y * u - C.y) ** 2;
        } else {
            // if closest point not on the line segment
            // use the unit distance to determine which end is closest
            // and get dist square to circle
            dist = u < 0 ?
                  (A.x - C.x) ** 2 + (A.y - C.y) ** 2 :
                  (B.x - C.x) ** 2 + (B.y - C.y) ** 2;
        }
        return dist < radius * radius;
     }
```

Comment: Which angle? Can you post a sketch?

Comment: I agree that your "angle" is not clear. Do you mean the angle between the given line and the line that goes through the point of intersection of the given line and circle and is tangent to the circle? (There are usually two intersection points--the angle that i defined above is the same for both.)